# ARC issues in iCrousel

Tags: ios5, automatic-ref-counting, coverflow

I'm using a [icarousel sample project from github](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) that creates a coverflow on iphone and ipad application with storyboard and ios 5. But Tehre are total 19 errors due to the ARC.

I have compiled it by disabling the ARC but that didn't solve my problem.

How can I fix this problem?

Any  help...

**EDIT**

I am using XCode 4.2 and Mac 10.6.8

Comment: What are the errors? iCarousel looks like it has been ARC-ified (albeit with horrible `#define`s) so it should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge iCarousel's newer version is not compatible with Xcode 4.2 try to update your xcode and use it. You can also download the older version on iCarousel and use it.

I never tried but older versions should work fine.

Hope that would help.